# Sharepoint 2010 local - login

Tags: windows, iis, networking, sharepoint-2010, localhost

I am trying to setup a local Sharepoint Server 2010 for testing purposes. I have never worked wih SP before, but it is per request from a client. And I am a strong fan of "learning-by-doing".

Everything is setup fine but when I try to access the Central Administration site it keeps asking me for user and password and I have no idea what that is. Is there something I am missing somewhere or forgot to set up. I have enable anonymous login in the IIS settings but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

I am logged in with my standard Windows user "Morten".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using Domail Controller Active directory user to login ?

IF yes then check that your PC is available in Domain Controller

also check ,

Go to IIS > Your SIte > Right click on your site and go to advanced settings > Check for the Idenetiy under Process Model Section .

It should same as your login.

Let me know the outcome

Comment: Isn't the Domain Controller only available in Windows Server? I am only running Windows 7 - sorry for not mentioning that i the question.

Comment: did u check the USer in Advanced settign it is the same as you are using to login ?

Comment: I actually got it to work by using the solution for "Resolved Blank white page" on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx